# Login in my webapp with auth0 not working on Iphone

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, auth0

I'm currently working on a React application that uses Auth0 for user authentication. Here is the url: https://trivify.es/tombola/test The login feature works perfectly fine when users access the application from an Android mobile browser. However, when users try to log in from an iPhone, they are unable to do so.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './sass/index.scss'
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react'
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'

const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: 'GTM-KMDVRPL'
}
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter basename='/tombola'>
            <Auth0Provider
                domain='trivify.uk.auth0.com'
                clientId='lxHR*****************18rlS'
                authorizationParams={{
                    redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/tombola/callback`,
                    audience: 'https://trivify.uk.auth0.com/api/v2/',
                }}
            >
                <App />
            </Auth0Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode> 
)
```

I've included my code from the index.js file that sets up the application with the Auth0Provider and BrowserRouter.

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? I suspect there may be compatibility issues with the iPhone browser, but I'm not sure how to resolve them.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not a code issue, but rather due to the browser not accepting 3rd Party cookies.  Auth0 uses cookies to maintain session information.  We had a similar issue and were able to resolve it by creating a 'Custom' domain within Auth0.

So the login will be at 'login.mycustomdomain.com' and your app is at 'app.mycustomdomain.com'. The cookies created will no longer be on a different domain (ie. your actual auth0 tenant domain).

This will stop browsers blocking the auth cookie as it will no longer be seen as 3rd party.